# checkboxes generated dynamically not inserting all values into array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query that selects all of the users in a database that are not approved.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE approved = '0';
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Then, what I want to do is display that list of people in a table that has a column with a checkbox to approve that person.

```
<table class="table mb-none">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Profile Type</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
            <th>Deny/Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

  <?php
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
      echo '<tr>'
            echo '<td><img width="70px" height:"90px" src="' . EHS_UPLOADPATH_STUDENTS . $row['picture'] . '"/></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>Student</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['last_name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['phone_number'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#DFF0D8;">';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value = "'.$row['user_id'].'"></td>';
            echo '<td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#FCDEDE;"><a href="profile_delete_info.php?user_id='. urlencode($row['user_id']) . '&amp;first_name=' . urlencode($row['first_name']) . '&amp;last_name=' . urlencode($row['last_name']) .'"><button type="button" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-danger">Deny/Delete</button></a>  </td>';
       echo '</tr>';}
```

[image]

This is how I am trying to process this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['approve'])){
        $users = $_POST['approve'];
        foreach($users as $user){
            $query = "UPDATE users SET approved = '1' WHERE user_id = '". $user . "'";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);}}} ** here goes the rest of the code
```

Now, the problem I am having is that when I click on the "approve" checkboxes and hit "Submit" only the first item in the array approve[] is being processed and not the rest. I have no idea why. I have been thinking about this for the last 2 hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: My user name is `1' or '1'='1` . Since it wouldn't take my user id, I edited the request to send my username instead!

Comment: Your code looks like it should work... Is your `<form>` tag wrapped around all elements?

Comment: Since you're using mysqli, why aren't you using parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: @EdwinKrause Yes, it is. The code works, but only for the first item in the array.

Comment: @Barmar To be honest with you I am just learning how to use PHP. Would you be willing to explain to me how I can do what you said? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't explain that in a comment, and it's not an answer to your question. Here's a tutorial: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: @Barmar I'll read it right away. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following approach :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['approve'])){
    foreach($_POST['approve'] as $user){
        $query = "UPDATE users SET approved = '1' WHERE user_id = '". $user . "'";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);}}} ** here goes the rest of the code
```

If that does not work ,do a print_r($_POST['approve']) and see what the contents of the array are.

Comment: I had no idea I could use that to print the array. It helped me see the array was OK. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this answer solves anything. Basically, all you did was skip the step of assigning to a variable. It should work the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... I put the closing bracket for the "foreach" in the wrong place. Thanks for your help!